# MVC View display items of a list contained within a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I wonder if someone could help me please.  I have a shopping basket which can contain products and each product can contain customers so for instance:

A basket contains the details of the 'purchaser' (FirstName, LastName, etc.) and 
Product details (product name, date, etc.) and each product will have 
Delegates (people actually attending the event....FirstName, LastName, etc.

What I'm trying to create is a form which shows all of the products with a list of fields underneath allowing the purchaser to enter/amend the names of the people that are attending the event:

[image]

What I'm struggling with though is to create the input fields for the attendees. I can use:

```
foreach(var dele in product.delegates)
{
    <p>@dele.FirstName</p>
}
```

Which does display a list of the names of the attendees as expected but I would expect to be able to use something like:

```
for(var i=0, i < product.delegates.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].FirstName)
}
```

But this displays the name (repeated) of the purchaser and not the attendees.

Could anyone assist please? Like I say I want to display a list of inputs that can amended and posted to an `ActionResult` to update the DB.

As a note I can see the model is populated with the information that I'm expecting.

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string TransStatus { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string StoreKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SentToStore { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartProduct> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ShoppingCartProduct
    {
        public int ShoppingCartProductId { get; set; }
        public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string CourseId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalPrice => ItemPrice * Quantity;

        public virtual ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartDelegate> delegates { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShoppingCartDelegate
    {
        public int ShoppingCartDelegateID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int ShoppingCartProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual ShoppingCartProduct ShoppingCartProduct { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please include your model class definition.

Comment: Done, please see above

Comment: Is the @Model defined in your view a ShoppingCart or an IEnumerable<ShoppingCart>? I'm guessing it's a collection since x[i] (in the case of x[i].FirstName) seems to be resolving to a ShoppingCart.

Comment: It's a ShoppingCart (not an IEnumerable) as there's only a single shopping cart item but it contains a 'list' of ShoppingCartProducts which in turn contains a 'list' of delegates. Thanks.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Even though you're iterating over the product.delegates with the For-Next loop, that's just generating product.delegates.Count instances of i. That doesn't really set any variables the way that a foreach loop would. There's no FirstName property in ShoppingCartProduct, so x must be iterating over multiple ShoppingCarts. Maybe if you posted the entire view that would shine some light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry buddy, it was me.....the objects were collections and not lists so I was never going to be able to iterate through them with an index. Sorted now. Thanks for you time :)